# MS Graph: How to determine the account type of logged in user?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

**Question**: Is there a way to query if a given email address is a 'Work or School' account against the Microsoft graph API?

I would like to authenticate against both Microsoft accounts and 'Work or School' accounts in a Azure multi-tenant environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, there is no a direct endpoint to query if this account is a work account or MSA.

Based on your description, you are using `common` authority to authenticate the user.

When you enter your username and password, the url in address bar will be:

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/******` for work account

**AND**

`https://account.live.com/Consent/******` for Microsoft accounts.

If you call `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me`, you will find that id of work account is like this `"id": "987932c9-f062-48e2-8ced-22cb6896dfce"` while id of an Microsoft account is like `"id": "5d9ee9b4b2ad3bfe"`.

Comment: I did not understand the URL part of your suggestion because in `Graph Explorer` I did not see the URL in the address bar. But your suggestion for `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me` call and using id formats for Work account and for the Microsoft account solved my issue (thank you). I don't have school account so I am not sure how will that work.

Comment: @nam If you are using Graph Explorer, the URL part can be ignored because it is only seen when you integrate AAD login into your application. School account is the same as work account.